# How to fix NodeJS problem in my FiveM server

Tags: node.js, node-modules, fivem

My FiveM server txAdmin show next error. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04. I haven't installed NodeJS on Ubuntu, do I need to?

If I have to do this, where should I install Node Modules?

[image: Error]